# How to prevent Ctrl + mouse click to open new tab?

Tags: javascript

I have a a link as below

```
<a href="#" onclick="function1()">link</a>
```

and javascript `function1` include submit form action

now I want to use JavaScript to prevent <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + mouse click to open new tab on this a link for IE(>=6), FF, and Chrome.

Updated to fix
1. update href="javascript:void(0)" 
2. update onclick="function1();return false;"

**Note:** I'm not using a JavaScript library such as jQuery or Dojo.

Comment: AFAIK since there is no target page it will not open a new tab with Ctrl + mouse click

Comment: Why do you think your website is so special that it can change a behavior users have come to expect?

Answer (score 1):

The A tag is used for links or references. If you mainly want a clickable function I would suggest to use the button tag and style it like a link with css.

For example, bootstrap does this with the btn-link class:

```
<button type="button" onclick="function()" class="btn btn-link">Link</button>
```

This has the advantage over using a span or div element that it is clear to browsers, search machines and screenreaders that this is supposed to be a clickable element.

Answer (score 0):

**[Edited]**

You can do whatever you want to do from within the event's function **(onclick)** and **don't use href** at all. For the mouse hover cursor effect use `style="cursor:pointer"`.

example code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function fn(){
        /* do something */
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a style="cursor:pointer" onclick="fn()">1234</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm worried about the effects on SEO if you do this (didn't downvote)

Comment: Please note the asker's target URL. Changing the address is not desired.

Comment: I don't know why people are outraged and not being objective here. so what if he wants to do that ? discourage him and tell him the solution. If he still wants to apply it, it is on himself to lose clients.

Comment: He does not want to change the URL! look where the link leads. You misunderstood the question.

Comment: If you remove the `href` doesn't that prevent the user from accessing the link via the keyboard?

Comment: @nnnnnn true .. but if you wish to make it focusable by keyboard use the tabindex attribute with the value 1 and add a keypress handler function to handle the Enter button (onkeypress) ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute a function on click of an element, use a div tag instead of an anchor tag

```
<div onclick="function1()" style="cursor:pointer">link</div>
```

EDIT: a div tag is a block element and will push the link to a new line. And as Jan has suggested move styles to a CSS. Used inline style for ease here.

```
<span onclick="function1()" style="cursor:pointer">link</span>
```

Comment: Also, I'm worried about the effects on SEO if you do this (didn't downvote)

Comment: Yes SEO is a concery, but I think here what he's trying to do is execute a function on click and not necessarily open a page. Don't know why people are down-voting. you need to understand what he wants. He doesn't want to open a webpage.

Comment: "use a div tag instead of an anchor tag" -- or any other element for that matter. Also please note inline styles are bad practice.

Comment: Even an `a` without `href` would do (though that kills the browser's default style for `a[href]`).

Comment: how's this different than my answer ?

Comment: @CME64 this answerer correctly understood that changing the URL is not desired. Remove the body of `fn` from your answer, and the answers will be the same